# Playing a movie with pygame in Python 3 with specific resolution

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, pygame, video-processing

I'm currently making a game on pygame (Python 3) and I want a small movie intro to be played at the beginning. I'm having several issue with the pygame.movie module and solutions to similar questions seem to not work for me. Is there an easy way to play an MPG movie onto a pre-existing screen?

I tried the following code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
movie = pygame.movie.Movie('intro.mpg')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(movie.get_size())
movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()

movie.set_display(movie_screen)
movie.play()
```

but that crashed python. When I tried

```
import pygame

FPS = 60

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
movie = pygame.movie.Movie('intro.mpg')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(movie.get_size())
movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()

movie.set_display(movie_screen)
movie.play()


playing = True
while playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            movie.stop()
            playing = False

    screen.blit(movie_screen,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

A screen appeared, and for some reason was filled with green squares. What did I do terribly wrong?

Secondly, the movie I have is 480*360 resolution, and the screen on which my game is played is 640*480. I'd like to have the video take up the whole screen -- is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you could run the video centered in the Surface and Screen

```
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 20
appActive = True
movie = pygame.movie.Movie('movie.mpg')

#full screen display
mainDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
offscreen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size())
movie.set_display(offscreen)

center = offscreen.get_rect()
center.center = mainDisplay.get_rect().center

while appActive:
    mainDisplay.blit(offscreen, center)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Your code seems alright, I tried it myself and it worked. I noticed that pygame is quite fuzzy on rendering movie on screen. If the dimensions of the screen can't fit the movie then it will crash. Did you have any luck so far with controlling movie sizes?